# If Statement in SharePoint Calculated Column Formula

Tags: sharepoint-designer, calculated-column-formula

this is my current formula(see below). Right now I am adding admendment, however I only want it to add admendment if request status - amendment but I need help with this formula

```
=[Date Formula]
 &" "
 &"SP"
 &" "
 &[SharePoint ID]
 &" "
 &[Contract Manufacturer Name]
 &"  "
 &[PeopleSoft Contract ID]
 &" "
 &"Amendment"
 &" "
 &[Contract Ancillary Number]
```

Answer (score 2):

Syntax would be - IF("specify condition", "if true", "if false")

IF([Request Status]="Amendment",[Amendment],"")

Try below

```
=[Date Formula]
 &" "
 &"SP"
 &" "
 &[SharePoint ID]
 &" "
 &[Contract Manufacturer Name]
 &"  "
 &[PeopleSoft Contract ID]
 &" "
 &IF([Request Status]="amendment",[Amendment]&" ","")
 &[Contract Ancillary Number]
```

Comment: At first glance this looks right except for the case where the IF statement is false. If false, you would end up with two spaces between [PeopleSoft Contract ID] and [Contract Ancillary Number]. You'll need to include the spacing in the IF statement.

Comment: You are absolutely right, made the correction

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I had to remove the brackets around Amendment

```
=[Date Formula]&" "&"SP"&" "&[SharePoint ID]&" "&[Contract Manufacturer Name]&" "&[PeopleSoft Contract ID]&" "&IF([Request Type]="Amendment","Amendment"&" ","")&[Contract Ancillary Number]
```